# Gatsby page in page

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm using gatsby js and trying to figure out how to have a page level side bar with Gatsby links that render a new component inside a div in the same page I can do this using react-router-dom but in Gatsby all I can find is how to create blog posts which is driving me nuts as every tutorial I find is the same blog post.

[image]

Here is my layout page /layouts/index.js

```
export default ({ children }) => (
  <div id="layout">
    <header>
      <h3>Header</h3>
      <MainNav />
    </header>
    {children()}
  </div>
)
```

**About Page**
/pages/about.js

```
export default ({ location, match }) => {
  console.log('location = ', location, 'match = ', match );
  return (
    <div id="about">
      <SideBar />
      <div id="content">
        // . add child template or component for link clicked in sidebar
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

What I'm trying to do is when a user clicks on a link in the side bar stay on about but render a new component or template based on the gatsby-link clicked in the about sidebar.

**The About SideBar component**
/components/about/side-bar.js

```
const SideBar = () => {
  return (
    <div id="side-bar">
      {/* <li><Link to='/about?sort=name'>work</Link></li> */}
      <li><Link to="/about/work">work</Link></li>
      <li><Link to='/about/hobbies'>hobbies</Link></li>
      <li><Link to='/about/buildings'>buildings</Link></li>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Problem with the links above, they are trying to go to a new page called. 
**/about/work**
This is not what I'm trying to do. Again I'm trying to make it stay on about but render a new component inside the content div.

Please help gatsby is so all over the place as far as docs goes. ok maybe its just me and not getting the docs clearly. 
Thanks

**UPDATE:** 
I tried adding a page suing createPage which works for me kind of but it doesn't pass the match.params id

**gatsby-node.js**

```
exports.createPages = ({ boundActionCreators }) => {
  const { createPage } = boundActionCreators;
  const myComponent = path.resolve('src/pages/about/index.js');
  createPage({
    path: '/about/:id',
    component: myComponent
  })
}
```

Comment: Pass some props  `<SideBar location={location} match={match}/>`and use them - search for 'conditional rendering' ?

Comment: Thanks xadm but the location will render a new page. I'm trying not to render a new page. Instead I want to render a template of a new component inside the <div id="content"> in the same about page.

Comment: router 'switches' components for different routes. When not using route than change a value in local state, pass it as prop to both (SideBar and Content) component. Inside them render conditionally what you need.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are saying. Gatsby Link is using routes under the hood, that's the whole purposes of it. I want to use Route so user can click back and forth in browser. Using local state is not going to produce that route behavior.

Comment: Routes will allways render entire page, not subcomponent but you can use common layouts (more complex structure than one component) in render of each 'entry points'.

Comment: Just clone 'about.js' and update content for all subroutes. React will minimize changes - it will look like only changing content subcomponent/div. But you can adjust SideBar, mark active selection, etc.

Comment: As I said you lost me. Do you have an example of what you mean ?

Comment: With react router dome I could do something like.     <Route path='/roster/:id' component={about}/> then I could get the id value in the match.params props and display the correct component inside my <div id="content">

Comment: I just added an update using gatsby-node.js but that still doesn't pass the /roster/:id to the match.params

Comment: look at (gatsby showcase) inspiration: https://angeloocana.com/en/resume/education/ > https://angeloocana.com/en/resume/languages/

Comment: You lost me again with that link ??

Comment: This is an example of common route/subroutes/layout - sources on github

Comment: I'm not seeing anything remotely close to what I'm after in my example image, but still an interesting link thanks

Comment: menu in footer is like submenu in sidebar; ResumeContainer is a common layout for all `resume` routes

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm not seeing how  ResumeContainer is doing what I'm trying to do. So if anyone has any other ideas or a quick example I would be grateful.

Comment: It contains menu (uses Link from gatsby-link) passed as prop. 

EducationsPage (and others) is linked from main menu (like router). .

For footer menu it uses own menu structure (its tricky created, just use common array of objects) passed to container (your layout with sidebar). Educations is a content (used in container as {props.children}).  This {props.children} is like content placeholder in template.

Answer (score 6):

After a long time of trying to understand Gatsby and I can say I still don't as its docs are vast and not very clear. But once I started to look at the node-apis and [onCreatePage](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#onCreatePage) it gave me some ideas. This is what the docs literally say.

> **onCreatePage**
>
> Called when a new page is created. This extension API is
>   useful for programmatically manipulating pages created by other
>   plugins e.g. if you want paths without trailing slashes.

So the only part in here that gives me a hint of this might be the key to helping me is this line. **useful for programmatically manipulating pages created by other
plugins**

Anyway this got me writing some code at least. Then about 3 hours later I found a plugin that was doing exactly what I was trying to do with this method. The plugin is called **[gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths)** key here is client-paths!!!!!

This makes life worth living! So in my case above I just wanted to be able to use Gatsby's router ( which is just react-router-dom behind the scenes), to pass me and id or value to routers match.params object. It still doesn't but what it does do is checks for any path after a prefix like **/folder/** in my case **'/about/work** and recreate the page with a template component (in my case keep using pages/about/index.js), which is my template. Now that we have about/index.js rendering for ever link after /about/ then we can use some internal switch statement to handle the location that is been passed to /about/index.js. Still don't get match.params update but I do get props.location.pathname; which allows me to extract everything after the prefix to use in a switch statement to render my specific components based on the routes pathname. Enough rabbiting on here is a rough solution to show as an example.

So add the plugin as an npm install. 
open up **gatsby.config.js** and add the below code to the exports.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths`,
      options: { prefixes: [`/about/*`] },
    },
  ]
}
```

**Then in my main about page `pages/about/index`**

```
import React from "react";
import SideBar from '../../components/about/side-nav';

export default (props) => {
  const { pathname } = props.location;
  var n = pathname.lastIndexOf('/');
  var pageId = pathname.substring(n + 1);

  const page = () => {
    switch(pageId){
      case '': 
        return (
          <div>Work Page</div>
        );
      case 'work':
        return (
          <div>Work Page</div>
        );
      case 'hobbies':
        return (
          <div>Hobbies Page</div>
        );
      case 'buildings':
      return (
        <div>buildings Page</div>
      );
    }
  }
  return (
    <div id="about">
      <SideBar />
      <div id="content">
        {page()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then in my sidebar I call it like this.

```
  <li><Link to="/about/work">work</Link></li>
  <li><Link to='/about/hobbies'>hobbies</Link></li>
  <li><Link to='/about/buildings'>buildings</Link></li>
```

Hopefully this will help someone else out. After all this I'm starting to really question the bulk of gatsby especially with docs not been very clear. Based on the response to my question I guess not many people in stackoverflow's community are using Gatsby which is worrying when you need help. It does look like Gatsby's github community is very helpful but that should be for bug issues and not for questions like mine, but encouraging to see.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I was about to post a new question about this exact situation , but your answer worked perfect - thanks!

Comment: Apparently this project is built into Gatsby itself and now obsolete. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths